# Create null instead of empty dictionary where IEnumerable has no data

Tags: c#, linq

Following is my Linq code, here we return a `Dictionary<string,object>`, while filling object value for each string key we internally fill the `Dictionary<string,string>`, which is `FieldPropertyMapping`in the code below

```
allCardColumnMappingFieldPropertyEntity
                   .GroupBy(column => (column.FieldDesc + column.OutputColumnId))
                   .ToDictionary(groupElement => groupElement.Key,
                                 groupElement => (object)groupElement.Select(currentElement =>
                                 {
                                    currentElement.FieldPropertyMapping =
                                     fieldPropertyEntity
                                     .Where(field => field.OutputColumnId == currentElement.OutputColumnId)
                                     .Where(field => field.FieldDesc == currentElement.FieldDesc)
                                     .ToDictionary(property => property.PropertyDesc, property => property.PropertyValue);
                                 return currentElement;
                                 }).FirstOrDefault());
```

Challenge we have in the current code we cannot have `currentElement.FieldPropertyMapping` as null at any time even if the `Where` clause find no matching record it will always lead to empty dictionary, but we have a business requirement to make it null if it is empty. I have done the following modification to fulfill the condition, but probably there's a better way to achieve it in Linq code, any pointer / suggestion

Modified code

```
allCardColumnMappingFieldPropertyEntity
                   .GroupBy(column => (column.FieldDesc + column.OutputColumnId))
                   .ToDictionary(groupElement => groupElement.Key,
                                 groupElement => (object)groupElement.Select(currentElement =>
                                 {
                                     List<DesignCardFieldProperty> localDesignCardFieldPropertyEntity = fieldPropertyEntity
                                         .Where(field => field.OutputColumnId == currentElement.OutputColumnId)
                                         .Where(field => field.FieldDesc == currentElement.FieldDesc).ToList();

                                     if(localDesignCardFieldPropertyEntity.Any())
                                        currentElement.FieldPropertyMapping = localDesignCardFieldPropertyEntity
                                            .ToDictionary(property => property.PropertyDesc, property => property.PropertyValue);

                                     return currentElement;
                                 }).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Why not set it to null if it is empty?

Comment: Modified code will do it, since property will not get initialized, I want modification to the original code

Comment: How is "modified code" _not_ a "modification to the original code"? Besides the fact that it's not clear what you're asking, there is also the issue that your code example is not simple enough, and at the same time is not complete. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Try with simple extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> NullIfEmpty<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        if (dictionary == null || !dictionary.Any())
        {
            return null;
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I have mentioned, I need to check whether a query result is empty then return null else the `List<T>` with data, your extension method is pretty simple, this may not resolve. Nonetheless +1 for your effort, since you have at least tried